# “Bad Data” exception when decrypting encrypted file

Tags: c#, file, encryption

When I want to DeserializeObject, it gives an error which says "Bad Data".

After file data conversion succeed, it gives error on disposing or closing stream

#########Error

```
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._DecryptData(SafeKeyHandle hKey, Byte[] data, Int32 ib, Int32 cb, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode PaddingMode, Boolean fDone)
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoAPITransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   at BinaryFileHelper.DeserializeObject[T](String filename)
```

#########Error

```
private static DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider()
{
    Key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345678".Substring(0, 8)),
    IV = new byte[] { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF }
};

public static void SerializeObject(string filename, object objectToSerialize)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, objectToSerialize);
        }
    }
}

public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string filename)
{
    T objectFromDeserialize;
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, cryptic.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            objectFromDeserialize = (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
        } // After conversion succeed, it gives error on disposing or closing at this line
    }
    return objectFromDeserialize;
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the usage of `OpenOrCreate` instead of `Create`. The reason being is that `OpenOrCreate` will create a `FileStream` for appending to the end of a file, if the file already exists. Whereas `Create` will delete the existing file before creating a new file.

```
public static void SerializeObject(string filename, object objectToSerialize)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create))//Changed
    {
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, objectToSerialize);
        }
    }
}
```